# Convergence of expectation

Tags: expected-value, convergence, moments

Suppose we have $X_n \overset{D}\to X$ for some sequence $X_{1},\dotsc, X_{n}$. Is it the case that if $E(X_{n}^2) \to E(X^2)$ we have it that $E(X_n) \to E(X)$, and when would it hold?

My first thought is that since we have $E(X_{n}^2) \to E(X^2)$ and convergence in distribution, we might somehow have convergence in mean square which would imply we have convergence in mean.

Comment: So here $P(X_n \leq n) = P(X_n = 0) = 1-(1/n)$ and $\lim F_{n}(x) = 1$ for $X_n \leq n$ and $\lim F_{n}(x) = 0$ for $X_n > n$?

Comment: Just to clarify, $x$ here is the $x$ in $P({X_n \leq x} = F_{n}(x)$?  Then isn't $P({X_{12} \leq 73731}) = 1$?

Comment: Yes, $P(X_{12} \leq 73731) = 1$. But what about $P(X_{10^6} \leq 73731$? Does it equal $1$ too? What about $P(X_{10^9}\leq 73731)$? Is it it $1$? Less than $1$ also? But how does the value of $P(X_{10^6} \leq 73731)$ compare to the value of $P(X_{10^9}\leq 73731)$? As $n$ increases, does $P(X_n \leq 73731)$ approach a limit?

Comment: Would $P(X_{10^6} \leq 73731)$ be 0?

Answer (score 1):

We may have a sequence $(X_n)_{n\geqslant 1}$ which converges in probability to $0$ but such that $\lim_{n\to +\infty}\mathbb E\left[X_n^2\right]$ is not $0$. For example, consider the set of positive integers and the probability measure $\mathbb P\{k\}=2^{-k}$, $k\geqslant 1$. Then define the random variable 
$X_n:=c_n\mathbb 1\{j\geqslant n\}$, where $\mathbf 1$ denotes the indicator function. For any choice of $c_n$, the sequence $(X_n)$ converges in probability to $0$. But given any positive $\lambda$, we can choose the sequence $(c_n)$ such that $\mathbb E\left[X_n^2\right]=\lambda$. 
With other choices of $(c_n)$, the sequence $\left(\mathbb E\left[X_n^2\right]\right)$ may even be unbounded, or oscillated between two or more values.

However, if $\lim_{R\to +\infty}\sup_{n\geqslant 1}\mathbb E\left[X_n^2\mathbf 1\{X_n^2\geqslant R \}\right]$ (uniform integrability), then we do have $\mathbb E\left[X_n^2\right]\to \mathbb E\left[X^2\right]$.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Skorokhod's representation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skorokhod%27s_representation_theorem), we may assume $X_n \to X$ almost surely without loss of generality.

Note also that $\vert X_n \vert \leq 1 + X_n^2$ and that, by assumption, $E(1 + X_n^2) \to 1 + EX^2$. Thus, **assuming** $EX_n^2 < \infty$, we get $EX_n \to EX$ using a [dominated convergence theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72174/general-lebesgue-dominated-convergence-theorem).

Note that this does not contradict the point made in other answers, namely that convergence in distribution alone, or in probability for that matter, does not imply convergence of $EX_n$ to $EX$.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other excellent answer, I will give a simple illustration explaining why you cannot expect (always) the means to converge, even if you have convergence in distribution.  There must be some extra conditions.  Look at the figure below:

[image: Plot of random angle generating a Cauchy distribution]

If we simulate the angle $\theta$ uniformly in $(0,\pi)$ then the point with $x$ coordinate $x=\frac1{\tan\theta}$ on the upper horizontal line will have the Cauchy distribution.

Define now a sequence of random variables with $X_n=\min(\max(-n, \frac1{\tan\theta}),n)$ (capping at $-n,n$) (for $n=1,2,\dotsc$).  Then $X_n$ will converge in distribution to the Cauchy distribution, but $\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{\mathbb{E}} \E X_n$ will converge to zero, since by symmetry $\E X_n =0$ for all $n$ (all limits when $n \rightarrow \infty$).   But the expectation of the Cauchy distribution do not exist.